# jquery theme builder CSS question

Tags: c#, php, javascript, jquery, css

How do I change the size of an icon from the JQuery theme builder? The icon is too small to use.

Setting height and width is wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icons are implemented as sprites within a single image. So you would have to resize that image and then calcualte the new dimension settings and manually change them in your theme CSS or override them in another stylesheet.

The thing is i dont think they offer an oversized raster version or a vector version, so if you just scale up the image you get with your theme download things are going to start looking pixelated.

Comment: well you can either use a seperate sheet and override the styles for `.ui-icon-%ICON_NAME%` or scan the css file for those styles. They will only containe a `background-position` declaration. Also its not really that annoying when you consider these icons are menat to be <= the size of the text they accompany. they arent meant to be standalone clickable icons but rather icons used on button faces or within a line of text (like next to an alert or info message). If you plan to use them as large clickable icons this probably isnt the way to go.

Comment: Scaling up the image won't look good? That's pretty limited in terms of using the icons... They're very small.

Comment: Ahh, so where would you recommend going for large clickable icons?

Comment: i dunno... usually i have a set provided to me by the designers i work with since they are control freaks :-) iStock is good for cheap vectors ($10-20 USD). As far as free im not sure... but google should help.